# Map given index from a vector to another one

Tags: r, function

I do have to vectors

```
x <- c(2,5,6) # index vector
y <- c(10:20)  # value vector
```

now, I have written a function giving me only the values from v2 descripted in v1. 
Example return value (11,14,15)

```
mapIdxToVector <- function(x,y) {
  ret <- c(x);
  for( i in 1:length(x) ) {
    ret[i] <- y[x[i]];
  }
  return(ret);
}
```

Is there any fancy function in R to improve my own one?

Sincerely
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing fancy to show, just take advantage of the way that R is intended to be used:

```
> y[x]
[1] 11 14 15
```

This is covered in the Intro to R Manual, you'll save yourself lots of time with a cursory perusal of this document: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors

Comment: Thank you. I red some manuals, but I still don't think r like.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop here. 
Just do

```
y[x]
```

As R handles vectors very well, almost every action you can do supports vectors.
So does indexing.